# iOS Modify local XML file

Tags: xml, cocoa, file, nsxmlparser, local

I'm using NSXMLParser to parse a local XML file on my iPad. Now I want to modify the file. I want to put some lines at the almost end of it.

This is what my file looks like:

```
<dict>
    <element att1="atribute" att2="atribute" att3="atribute" att4="atribute" />
    <element att1="atribute" att2="atribute" att3="atribute" att4="atribute" />
    <element att1="atribute" att2="atribute" att3="atribute" att4="atribute" />
    <element att1="atribute" att2="atribute" att3="atribute" att4="atribute" />
</dict>
```

How could I solve this? I tried to load a dictionary or array "with contents of file..." but it always returned (null) in the log.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your exact code for loading the file?

Comment: The XML file is pulled form an API into the documents directory of the app: `NSData *data = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://.../get.php"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [data writeToFile:xmlPath atomically:YES];` I'm now creating a new entry and passing it back to the API. Now I want to add the entry to the local file too so that I don't have to download entire file again (it's very large).

Comment: And where along here is the error happening?

Comment: There is no error... I'm searching for a solution how I can do this!

Answer (score 1):

Use `GDataXML` to add data to XML file. You can find a tutorial for writing to xml [Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml)